# Search multiple User-inputted Text fields in database

Tags: php, mysql

Here's The code we have tried so far.
What actually we have to do is user will input data in his selected textboxes. we want php query to combine the search result and provide output.

```
    $query=array();
    $query[] = empty($_POST['keyword_s_dec']) ? : 'cand_desc='.$_POST['keyword_s_dec'];
    $query[] = empty($_POST['keyword_s_location']) ? : 'cand_location='.$_POST['keyword_s_location'];
    $results = implode('AND', $query);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate where '".$results."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Where keyword_s_dec & keyword_s_location are our texfield ID;
        cand_desc & cand_location are database columns.

Also we are trying for SQL Injection how can we achieve this?

Comment: Can you show the query generated?

Comment: We are trying above query,but its giving error as "Unexpected ':' "

Comment: "we are trying for SQL Injection how can we achieve this?"  What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: @Gordon..I heard about sql injection but how to code it ? Can you give some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some adjustments to your code:

```
$query = array();

if (!empty($_POST['keyword_s_dec'])) $query[] = "cand_desc = '".$_POST['keyword_s_dec']."'";
if (!empty($_POST['keyword_s_location'])) $query[] = "cand_location = '".$_POST['keyword_s_location']."'";

$condition = implode(' AND ', $query);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE $condition";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

This builds a valid query:

```
SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cand_desc = 'test1' AND cand_location = 'test2'
```

Your main issue was that you weren't inserting spaces around the `AND` string and single quotes for the values in the `WHERE` clause, but I also removed the conditional `?:` operator since it made the code less readable.

**Note that I only fixed the code that you wrote. It won't work if none of the `POST` variables are set (since then the SQL string will have a WHERE clause without any content) and you should definitely use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when reading the `POST` variables to prevent SQL injection.**

Comment: @Samuel..This has worked for me. Thank a lot. :) You are right and the problem was with single quotes and spaces between AND. Thank you once again.